MIPS Assembly--> BEQ
I'm using MARS 4.5 like editor to coding in Assembly Mips.
Today I'm learning BEQ, however I have a problem with this code:
.data

Message_1: .asciiz "I numeri sono uguali"


Stampa:
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, Message_1
    syscall


.text
main:

addi $t1, $zero, 3
addi $t2, $zero, 3

    beq $t1, $t2, Stampa

Error in : invalid program counter value: 0x10010014
Some advice?
I'm looking to implement beq in MIPS Assembly

For starters, the .text is in the wrong place. Should be before your Stampa.

Also obviously your Stampa will again fall through into main and your program has no ending.

Yes, but if .text is before "Stampa", the syscall print always "Stampa" also if the branch is not equal.

Apparently MARS doesn't care about main and just starts executing at the first instruction. Move your code around so that main is first. Also add a jr $ra to exit the program before falling through into Stampa which itself should also end with a return.

You need a syscall 10 at the end of the code to return to the operating system.  Check https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/CCSC-CP%20material/Fibonacci.asm  The IDE has a built-in debugger.  Have you single-stepped through to figure out what's going on?  That should always be step 1.

@Jester, MARS has an option, which is set by default: "Initialize Program Counter to global 'main' if defined".  However, this requires both a main label, as well as a .globl declaration for main — and if both are not present, then no errors, just starts at .text.

There are 3 main bugs in your program:

Misplaced instructions in the data segment.


Error: invalid program counter value: 0x10010014

This error occurs because the program has two main segments, data and instructions, stored in separate parts of memory.



All code after .data: in the data segment.




All code after .text: in the instruction segment.


The function Stampa, as a part of the instructions, should be placed after the .text. If Stampa is incorrectly placed in the data segment, the beq statement will attempt to point the program counter (PC) to an address in the data segment.

Both memory segments have different permissions associated with them.



.text : read + execute (no write).




.data : read + write (no execute).


So, the program tries to execute code from a non-executable area, which gives : invalid program counter value



There is no exit system call.


Exit system control is required for smooth flow of the program.


Didn't include .globl main


After correcting these 3 bugs the program becomes:
   .globl main

.data # data segment
Message_1: .asciiz "I numeri sono uguali"

.text # instruction segment

main: # main function

addi $t1, $zero, 3
addi $t2, $zero, 3
beq $t1, $t2, Stampa

# exit system call
end:
li $v0, 10
syscall

# Stampa function
Stampa:
li $v0,4
la $a0, Message_1
syscall

j end


As discussed in comments, there's a third bug: you need .globl main, otherwise execution will start at the top of .text.  (Which isn't where you've put main).  Also, if the values weren't equal, execution would fall off the end of main.  It doesn't make sense to write a conditional branch where the fall-through path is into padding bytes after the end of your asm, unless you comment it as a reminder or something.  An all-zero instruction word in MIPS is unfortunately nop, so execution will keep going until it hits something else or an invalid page.

Since the PC is designed to point to values in the instruction segment, - A better way to say this is that .data pages have read + write but not execute permission.  .text has read + exec but not write.

@peter-cordes , Thanks for the corrections. Could you clarify something for me? Is .globl main required for standalone programs? Additionally, even after including .globl main, execution begins with the first instruction after .text, not at the main: label. What is the purpose of the main: label, then?

I looked again at comments under the question, specifically this one - MARS has an option Initialize Program Counter to global 'main' if defined , IDK if it's enabled by default.  If it's not enabled .globl main; main: would do nothing.  If it is, then execution starts at main:,  wherever you put it.  In a program for Linux MIPS for example, you'd need to make main a global symbol if you're building with GCC for it to link a crt.o with a _start that calls your main

Reordering the program like you did to put the desired entry point at the start of the .text section makes it work either way, so probably a good idea.  In that case .globl main / main: isn't needed for the MARS simulator to run it.

each of your instruction needs to be under .text so write stampa after text and all set

As discussed in comments, that's not the only bug, just the one that causes the error mentioned in the question.
